# Adding "trigger" post-data load

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have an API feeding data into our datawarehouse in real time.
So far, we excluded fields with PII- however we would like to start including `email` and `name` as part of the feed.

Note that after adding these two fields, we can only have `email` and `name` populate if a different field called `partner` is not null (this is not something we can set-up via the API so have to do it after data load) due to contractual obligations.

So if `partner` is null: `email` and `name` should be overwritten as null.
If `partner` is not null: `email` and `name` should stay as they are (provided by the API).

Can you please assist with a way to set-up an appropriate "trigger" for this Redshift table? ie. let API load as is, and after each row loads- if `partner` is null- make `email` and `address` null as well. Thank you!

Comment: please explain the nature and method of "We have an API feeding data into our datawarehouse in real time"

Comment: @JonScott This is what I am referring to if you need to know details: https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/integrations/webhooks/stitch-incoming-webhooks. However, I only mentioned it to explain that we have an ETL that brings data into Redshift on continuous replication basis, and after it brings the data in- we would like to clean up the data as per the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no trigger system inside redshift.

If you cannot do that transformation on the sending side or within stitch, and it is important that the data is secure, here is what I would do.

1. Set up stitch to write data to a redshift "staging" schema, which
   has locked down security so that no normal users can see the data.
2. Set up a set of redshift etl scripts to run on a regular basis (using crontab, airflow or similar to manage the scheduling),
   which takes the new data as it arrives on the "staging" schema and
   populates a "reporting" schema. the timing of this should be aligned
   to the timing of the stitch runs. This sql will make the changes as
   you require based on "partner".

There is another option, to point stitch at a postgres instance as the target, use a postgres trigger and then use AWS DMS to continuously replicate that data over to redshift. that would work well but may cost a little more.

Comment: Thank you that's what I figured just wanted to make sure I am not missing any options.

Comment: I wonder whether you could do this with a view. create a view that implements this logic and then give access to that view but not the original table.